# javascript: how to remove comma(,) between two special character using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i know this is very simple question but i start learning reg-ex, so please provide solution..

### **i want to remove comma if exist between @ and .(dot) from the email id provided by user.**

**input**

> abc@gm,ail.com, xyz@nauk,ri.com, srs@y,ahoo.com, efgh@hot,mail.com

;

**desired output**

> abc@gmail.com, xyz@naukri.com, srs@yahoo.com, efgh@hotmail.com

---

i want to add one more part in this question , i don't know if it is possible if yes then please tell me..

input

> "joan,lee@gma,il.com, mohd,saeed@nau,kri.com, xX,yz@yaho,o.com"

Desired output

> joanlee@gmail.com, mohdsaeed@naukri.com, xXyz@yahoo.com"

thnx in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
email = email.replace(/@([^.]+)\./g, function(text, p1) {
    return text.replace(/,+/g, '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the examples:

```
'abc@gm,ail.com, xyz@nauk,ri.com, srs@y,ahoo.com, efgh@hot,mail.com'.replace(/(@[^\s,]+),([^\s\.].)/g, '$1$2')
```

Two:

```
'abc@gm,ail.com, xyz@nauk,ri.com, srs@y,ahoo.com, efgh@hot,mail.com'.replace(/,([^\s])/g, '$1')
```

Comment: thanx a lot it's solve my problem......but only just for knowledge i want to ask, Is this a shortest way to do this ?

Comment: If the format string with the email does not change, then you can: `'abc@gm,ail.com, xyz@nauk,ri.com, srs@y,ahoo.com, efgh@hot,mail.com'.replace(/,([^\s])/g, '$1')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
input = input.replace(/(@.*?),/g, '$1');
```

This one must be more reliable :

```
input = input.replace(/,(?! )/g, '');
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert this string("joan,lee@gma,il.com, mohd,saeed@nau,kri.com, xX,yz@yaho,o.com") in to this("joanlee@gmail.com, mohdsaeed@naukri.com, xXyz@yahoo.com")... thanx in advance..

Comment: @MohammadSaeedKhan I guess so : `/,(?! )/g` :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your kind of cooperation i succeed to achieve what i want. Below is explanation

```
var str = ",;ab'c@gm;ail.com,xyz@nauk'ri.com,srs@y;ahoo.co'm,efgh@hot;mail.com;"
str.replace(/,/g,', ').replace(/[';]/g,',').replace(/,(?! )/g,'').replace(/^,|,$/g,'').trim()
```

---

**Step1:** replace all comma(,) with (comma +whitespace)

```
str.replace(/,/g,', ')
```

**output** :   `", ;ab'c@gm;ail.com, xyz@nauk'ri.com, srs@y;ahoo.co'm,
efgh@hot;mail.com;"`

---

**Step2:** replace all semicolon(;) and single quote(‘) with comma

```
str.replace(/,/g,', ').replace(/[';]/g,',')
```

**output** : `", ,ab,c@gm,ail.com, xyz@nauk,ri.com, srs@y,ahoo.co,m, efgh@hot,mail.com,"`

---

**Step3:** remove all comma which not suffix whitespace (except those comma whose comes with whitespace)

```
str.replace(/,/g,', ').replace(/[';]/g,',').replace(/,(?! )/g, '')
```

**output** : `", abc@gmail.com, xyz@naukri.com, srs@yahoo.com, efgh@hotmail.com"`

---

**Step 4:** remove comma from the starting and ending.

```
str.replace(/,/g,', ').replace(/[';]/g,',').replace(/,(?! )/g, '').replace(/^,|,$/g,'')
```

**output** : `" abc@gmail.com, xyz@naukri.com, srs@yahoo.com, efgh@hotmail.com"`

---

**Step 5:** remove whitespaces from the starting and ending

```
str.replace(/,/g,', ').replace(/[';]/g,',').replace(/,(?! )/g, '').replace(/^,|,$/g,'').trim()
```

**output** : `abc@gmail.com, xyz@naukri.com, srs@yahoo.com, efgh@hotmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your own answer :

```
var s = ",;ab'c@gm;ail.com,xyz@nauk'ri.com,srs@y;ahoo.co'm,efgh@hot;mail.com;";
```

Step 1 - Clean up :

```
s = s.replace(/^[ ,;']+|[ ;']+|[ ,;']+$/g, '');
// "abc@gmail.com,xyz@naukri.com,srs@yahoo.com,efgh@hotmail.com"
```

Step 2 - Make-up :

```
s = s.replace(/,/g, ', ');
// "abc@gmail.com, xyz@naukri.com, srs@yahoo.com, efgh@hotmail.com"
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have `var email = 'bob@gm,ail.com'`

use:

```
var emailReplace = email.replace(/\,/g,'');
```

where emailReplace will now be bob@gmail.com

Update:

```
var emails = 'bob@g,mail.com, bob@ya,ooo.co.uk, bob@hot,mail.ca';

function fixCommas() {
    var fixedEmails = emails.replace(/,(?! )/g, '');
    return fixedEmails;
}

fixCommas(emails);
```

Comment: Good catch, I was caught looking into the function and posted this. This parsing will only need done to the '@-.' of the string, as you've stated above.